# VScode how to "Jump to definition" in other repo?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I have ~/code/projectA and ~/code/libraryC

I got these by git clone git@projectA and git clone git@libraryC in ~/code/.

projectA has libraryC in it but of course not the source code.

I want it so that if I ctrl+click ("Jump to definition") it goes to where the function is defined in libraryC. Currently I have to manually find it in another window.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: how is projectA depending upon projectC? show a [mre].